# How to call an objects values inside a separate method?

Tags: java

I've set up a simple program that creates an object with an `x` and a `y` value, and functions to return those values. I would like to create a method that calculates the distance between two points but I'm unsure how to syntax having an input that's a non set object, so you could call any two points you wanted to find their distance

My failed attempt:

```
public double distance(Point)
  {
     return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x - Point.getX()),2) + Math.pow((this.y - Point.getY()),2));
  }
```

The object before it I know is input as `obj.distance(blahblah)`, but I don't know how to get the argument to be any object I've set up previously to then call its `X` and `Y` values.

TLDR: I want to be able to read an objects variables inside of my method, but I don't know how to call an object without it being explicitly defined to a certain name

Comment: Sounds like you want a `static` method.

Comment: First of all you should declare what you're putting into the function what is Point ? is it a string your object? Then just use the object getters to retrieve the wanted values.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `Point` should be a specific instance

Comment: What do you mean by a "non set object"? Giving the parameter a name doesn't tie it to a particular method to a particular object as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Did you mean `public double distance(Point p) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x - p.getX()),2) + Math.pow((this.y - p.getY()),2));}`?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your Point type argument a paramater name.

```
 public double distance(Point pointArg) {
       return Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow((this.x - pointArg.getX()),2) +
                  Math.pow((this.y - pointArg.getY()),2)
                  );
}
```